# Use global gulp in a project

Tags: gulp, command-line-interface

How can I use globally installed gulp in a project where I have `gulpfile.js` without installing gulp in that project or linking it to global gulp.

When I type

```
$ gulp --version
```

I get:

> CLI version 3.9.1

but when I type:

```
$ gulp
```

I get:

> Local gulp not found in

I do not want any additional files nor directories created in the path-of-my-project just want to use globally installed gulp.

I want to use the gulp in the project-dir or pass the path to project-dir as a parameter.

In the project-dir I have only `gulpfile.js` and want to have only that file related to gulp.

How to do that?

Comment: Have you installed gulp-cli globally ?
`npm install gulp-cli -g`

Comment: I used command `RUN npm install gulp -g` in the Dockerfile